# Remove Switch Toggle padding in Flutter

Tags: flutter, button, switch-statement, toggle, padding

I would like to remove switch toggle paddings (left and right) in Flutter but I don't find the class property.
Do you have an idea how to do it ?

[see toggle button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVJcG.png)

```
ListTile(
 leading: Switch(
  value: _con.user.isAvailable,
  onChanged: (bool value) {
   setState(() {
    _con.user.isAvailable = value;
    updateAvailability(_con.user);
   });
 },
),
 title: Text(
  (_con.user.isAvailable) 
   ? S.of(context).availability 
   : S.of(context).unavailability,
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
 ),
),
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add your code ....

Comment: I added the code

Comment: It is default padding you can't remove . You can use CustomSwitch from flutter pub.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any padding there but can you try this

```
MediaQuery.of(context).removePadding()
```

For ListTile you can try

```
ListTile(
     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
   )
```

Comment: I get an error when i tried this, I think Mir Mahfuz answer could be the solution : Custom Switch from flutter pub. Thank you